# jQuery, how to influence the order of running of binded events?

Tags: jquery

say, I have two submit events:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    console.log('1');
});

$('form').submit(function() {
    console.log('2');
});
```

when submitting, I will get `1, 2` of course. How to get `2, 1` ? How could the secondly attached event be the first? I cant put there two functions into one, since its a 3rd library. And the 2nd submit influences the first

Answer (score 1):

> I cant put there two functions into one, since its a 3rd library. And the 2nd submit influences the first

That's unfortunate, as it would be the best way to address the problem.

> How to get 2, 1 ?

By attaching the second handler first.

> How could the secondly attached event be the first?

You can't.* jQuery runs the handlers in the order in which they were attached. If the first handler were attached using delegation, you might be able to get in front of it, but not if it's attached directly as shown.

---

* You can't *reasonably*. You could by hacking jQuery internals, since jQuery maintains its own list of event handlers. But the internals can change with each jQuery "dot" release (e.g., v3.3.1 => v3.3.2) without notice, so it's fragile to do so...

Answer (score 0):

What if you put one inside the other?

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  console.log('2');

  $('form').submit(function() {
      console.log('1');
  }).submit();
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/submit/